# Let $\alpha>0$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\sin nx\over n^\alpha}$ converges for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and examine continuity of the limit function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, sequence-of-function

First of all I have proved that this series of functions

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\sin nx\over n^\alpha}$$

converges $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}$.
Let $f_n(x)=\sin nx$ and $g_n(x)=\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$.
Let us fix $x\in\Bbb{R}$.
Now, let $a_n=f_n(x)$ and $b_n=g_n(x)$.

- Now if $x=2m\pi$ for some $m\in\Bbb{Z}$, $a_n=0$, hence the series $\sum a_nb_n$ converges to $0$.
- Now we assume $x\ne2m\pi$ for any $m\in\Bbb{Z}$.
  Then the partial sums of $(a_n)$ to be $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$. Then
  $$ \left| A_n \right| = \left| \sin x + \sin 2x + \cdots + \sin nx \right| = \left|\frac{\sin{\frac{nx}{2}}\sin {\frac{(n+1)x}{2}}}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}\right| \le \frac{1}{\left|\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\right|} $$
  and $\frac{1}{\left|\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\right|} \in \Bbb{R}$ since $x \ne 2m\pi$.
  So, partial sums of $(a_n)$ are bounded. Again $b_n={1\over n^\alpha}$ is monotone decreasing and converges to $0$.
  Hence by Dirichlet's test the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ converges.

Thus the series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n^\alpha}$ converges for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$.

---

Let

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n^\alpha} $$

**My target is to find where the function $f$ is continuous.**

Let us choose a point $a\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $a\ne2m\pi$ for any $m\in\Bbb{Z}$.
Now we can always find a compact interval $I$ containing $a$ such that $\sin \frac{x}{2} \ne 0$ $\forall x\in I$ since we have chosen $a\ne2m\pi$. Since, $I$ is compact interval and $\sin$ function is continuous we have $\min_{x\in I}\lvert \sin \frac{x}{2} \rvert = m > 0 $.

We will show that the series of functions $\sum f_n g_n$ converges uniformly on $I$ by using Dirichlet's test for the series of functions.
Let $(F_n)$ denotes the sequence of partial sums of $(f_n)$.
Then for all $x\in I$, $\left|F_n(x)\right|\le \frac{1}{\lvert\sin\frac{x}{2}\rvert}\le\frac{1}{m}$, hence the sequence of functions $(F_n)$ is uniformly bounded over $I$.
Again, the sequence of function $g_n(x)={1\over n^\alpha}$ is monotone decreasing and converging uniformly to $0$ function.
Thus by Dirichlet's Test for series of functions the series of functions $\sum f_n(x)g_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{n^\alpha}$ converges uniformly over $I$.
Since the functions $f_n g_n$ are continuous on $I$, the limit function $f$ is continuous on $I$.
In particular since $a\in I$, $f$ is continuous at $a$.

**So I found $f$ is continuous on the set $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{2m\pi \mid m\in\Bbb{Z}\}$.**

**But what about the points like $2m\pi$? I observed that $f$ is $0$ at those points.
I am getting no idea how to check continuity at those points.**

Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: hint: for $\alpha >1$ one has absolute convergence hence uniform continuity; for $\alpha=1$ the Fourier series is known - check Fourier series of the fractional part - (the result is bounded but discontinuous); for $0 \le \alpha <1$ show that $f$ is unbounded near $0$ of the order $x^{\alpha-1}, x>0, x \to 0$ - to show unboundness is easy by taking the partial sums from $n$ to $2n$ for some small $x$ so all the $sin kx$ are positive and at least $1/2$ say there; to show the order of unboundness is a bit trickier but one can start from $(1-z)^{\alpha-1}, |z| <1$ and let $|z| \to 1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $0<\alpha$.  We wish to examine the continuity of the function $f(x;\alpha)$ as represented by the series

$$f(x;\alpha)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}\tag1$$

Dirichlet's test guarantees that for each $\delta>0$, the series in $(1)$ converges uniformly for $x\in [2k\pi+\delta,(2k+1)\pi-\delta]$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Hence, $f(x;\alpha)$ is continuous on $(2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi)$.

---

Inasmuch as $f(x;\alpha)$ is odd and $2\pi$-periodic in $x$, it is sufficient, without loss of generality, to test the right-sided continuity of $f(x;\alpha)$ at $x=0$.  To that end, we begin with a motivational analysis to provide possible insight.

---

---

> **MOTIVATIONAL ANALYSIS:**

The first term in the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula for the series in $(1)$ is the integral $I(x;\alpha)$ given by

$$I(x;\alpha)=\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(xt)}{t^\alpha}\,dt\tag2$$

Enforcing the substitution $t\mapsto t/x$ in $(2)$ reveals for $x>0$

$$x^{\alpha-1}\int_x^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t^\alpha}\,dt\tag3$$

We might anticipate, therefore, from $(3)$ that for $x>0$, $f(x;\alpha)$ is $(i)$ continuous at $0$ from the right for $\alpha>1$, $(ii)$ jump discontinuous with jump size $\pi/2$ at $x=0$ from the right for $\alpha=1$, and $(iii)$ unbounded as $x\to 0^+$ for $\alpha <1$.

In the next section, we show that this is indeed the case.

---

---

> **REFINED ANALYSIS**

We begin by using summation by parts on the series in $(1)$ to write $f(x;\alpha)$ as

$$\begin{align}
f(x;\alpha)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\left(n^{-\alpha}-(n+1)^{-\alpha}\right)\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kx)\right)\\\\
&=\csc\left(\frac x2\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sin\left(\frac{nx}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{(n+1)x}2\right)\left(n^{-\alpha}-(n+1)^{-\alpha}\right)\right)\tag4
\end{align}$$

Applying the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula to the series on the right-hand side of $(4)$, we find

$$\begin{align}
S_N(x;\alpha)&=\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\sin(nx/2)\sin((n+1)x/2)\left(n^{-\alpha}-(n+1)^{-\alpha}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\int_1^N \sin\left(\frac{xt}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{xt}2+\frac x2\right)\left(t^{-\alpha}-(t+1)^{-\alpha}\right)\,dt\\\\
&+\left(1-2^{-\alpha}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x}2\right)\sin\left(x\right)\\\\
&+\int_1^N \frac{d}{dt}\left(\sin\left(\frac{xt}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{xt}2+\frac x2\right)\left(t^{-\alpha}-(t+1)^{-\alpha}\right)\right)\left(t-\lfloor t\rfloor\right)\,dt\tag5
\end{align}$$

---

Equipped with $(5)$, we are now prepared to analyze the behavior of $f(x;\alpha)$ as $x\to 0^+$.  We begin as we did with $(2)$ by enforcing the substitution $t\to t/x$ in the first integral on the right-hand side of $(5)$ and let $N\to \infty$ to find that asymptotically for $x\to 0^+$

$$\begin{align}
I_1(x;\alpha)&=\int_1^\infty \sin\left(\frac{xt}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{xt}2+\frac x2\right)\left(t^{-\alpha}-(t+1)^{-\alpha}\right)\,dt\\\\
&= x^{\alpha-1}\int_x^\infty \sin\left(\frac{t}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{t}2+\frac x2\right)\left(t^{-\alpha}-(t+x)^{-\alpha}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\alpha x^{\alpha}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{t}2\right)}{t^{1+\alpha}}\,dt+O(x^{1+\alpha}) \\\\
&=\alpha \left(\frac x2\right)^\alpha \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(t)}{t^{1+\alpha}}\,dt+O(x^{1+\alpha})\\\\
&=\frac12 x^\alpha \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t^\alpha}\,dt+O(x^{1+\alpha})
\end{align}$$

---

Next, the second term on the right-hand side of $(5)$ is $O(x^2)$.

---

Finally, it is straightforward to show that the second integral in $(5)$ is $O(x^{1+\alpha})$ as $x\to 0^+$.

---

> **CONCLUSION**

Putting it all together, we assert that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}=x^{\alpha-1}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t^{\alpha}}\,dt+O(x^\alpha)}\tag6$$

---

Evidently, $f(x;\alpha)$ is continuous at $0$ when $\alpha>1$, $f(x;\alpha)$ has a discontinuous jump of $\pm \pi/2$ as $x\to 0^\pm$ when $\alpha=1$, and $f(x;\alpha)$ is unbounded as $x\to 0$ when $0<\alpha<1$.  This supports the supposition discussed in the Motivational Analysis section.

---

Comment: good solution (+1) - the asymptotic term for $0<\alpha <1$ also can be given as $(\Gamma(1-\alpha) \cos \frac{\pi \alpha}{2})x^{\alpha-1}$

Comment: @Conrad Thank you!  Much appreciated.  Aside from this approach, I let $M_x=\lfloor \frac\pi x\rfloor$ and wrote $$\begin{align}f(x;\alpha)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{n=2kM_x +1}^{(2k+1)M_x}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}-\sum_{n=(2k+1)M_x +1}^{(2k+2)M_x}\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n^\alpha} \right)
\end{align}$$At this point, it was tempting to "approximate" each sum by evaluating $n^{-\alpha}$ at the midpoint of the summation limits.  This does lead to a result that is $O(x^{\alpha-1})$, but doesn't yield the correct answer.  Is there a way to proceed here or a better way?  Or is there an alternative?

Comment: Not sure about this -doing  $(1-z)^{\alpha-1}$ and letting $|z| \to 1$ gives the asymptotic immediately from the binomial coefficients asymptotic and the $\sin x$ about $x$ near zero

Comment: Hi @MarkViola, cannot upvote twice for this question, but it helps to solve this recent [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4674760/121671) if you are interested.